# How to assign count of rows or getText to a variable in Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor

**Here is my code:**

```
describe('SuperCalculator Page', function() {

  beforeEach(function(){
      browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('get rows count and firs column value', function() {

      element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
      element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);
      element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

      element(by.css('table[class=\'table\']')).all(by.css('tr')).count().then(function(rowCount) {
          counttim = rowCount;
          console.log(counttim);
      });

      element(by.css('table[class=\'table\'] > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function(text) {
          timeTocheck = text;
          console.log(timeTocheck,counttim );
      });
  });
});
```

Is there a way to use `timeTocheck` and `counttim` outside of this `then` structure? I want to save the value and use it in other place.
I just want to do something like:

```
var myTime = element(by.css('table[class=\'table\'] > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)')).getText();
```

and in `myTime` to have a string value that I can use later...
I want to do the same for the number of rows.

```
var rowNumbers = element(by.css('table[class=\'table\']')).all(by.css('tr')).count()
```

I don't want to compare them I want to use them please help.....

Comment: How and when do you want to use the values? You can assign the resolved values to variables of outer scope or global but it's only after the promises are resolved. So, the timing is crucial.

Comment: I want to use row count like counter in "For" sickle and the value of time I want to save in array. That's why I want to get these values out from "promise". But I look protractor from 3 days and I am new in JS too. So I don't know how to get these values and use them... outside this then structure...

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this is a real problem with asynchronous code like Protractor, and one that I encounter a lot. The problem is that all your commands are placed in the Command Queue before they execute, so attempting to put gettext() into a variable and use it later (for example, to check consistency across pages) requires a deep understanding of the difference between "parse time" and "run time."

Your best option is to do something like this:

```
describe('SuperCalculator Page', function() {

  beforeEach(function(){
      browser.get('http://juliemr.github.io/protractor-demo/');
  });

  it('gets row count and first column value', function() {

      // Declare your variables here so they'll be available in lower scopes
      var counttim, timeToCheck;

      element(by.model('first')).sendKeys(1);
      element(by.model('second')).sendKeys(2);
      element(by.id('gobutton')).click();

      element(by.css('table[class=\'table\']')).all(by.css('tr')).count().then(function(rowCount) {
          counttim = rowCount;
          console.log(counttim);
      })
      .then(function() {
          element(by.css('table[class=\'table\'] > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td:nth-child(1)')).getText().then(function(text) {
              timeToCheck = text;
              console.log(timeToCheck,counttim );
          });
      })
      .then(function() {
          // The rest of your program can go here (as many statements as
          //    needed), and it can actually use the variables you picked 
          //    up earlier because it's chained to a then() statement, so 
          //    they don't compute until the promises resolve.
          //
          // Just refer to them by name, like this:
          // expect(counttim).toEqual(1);
          // expect(timeToCheck).toEqual(3);
      });
  });
});
```

This is an ugly way to do things, because it adds a layer of nested brackets/parentheses, but it works fine. If you need to grab more variables later, just end the current then() and stick on another one (multiple nesting with then() statements is bad practice).

I don't particularly like this solution, so I am in search of another one (even if I have to code it myself), but for now this is the best I've found.

Comment: A year later, I'm starting to feel like you don't need so many `then()` statements in the code. You can probably put the last two `then()` blocks inside of the first one without any trouble.

Answer (score -1):

to get Row count:

```
var count=element.all('Here css locator').count();
```

to get text of a variable:

```
var row=element.all('here css locator').get(INDEX of Row);
var text=row.element('here variable css locator').getText();
```