# Protractor Angular cannot get the count of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm trying to write a test where I check the ammount of items in a ng-repeat. After that I add 1 item to that ng-repeat and I want to see if the old value+1 is equal to the new value.

This is my html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="list in listData.myLists">...</tr>
```

And my test

```
describe("list test", function(){
    it('Description of the test', function(){
        browser.get('app/#/list');

        var list = element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists'));
        var ammount;

        list.count().then(function(c) {
            ammount = c;
        });

        ... Here I add an item


        var secondAmmount = element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists')).count();

        expect(secondAmmount).toEqual(ammount + 1);
    });
});
```

But I'm getting 7 is not equal to NaN.

I have also tried just adding the list.count() + 1 directly into the toEquals method but then I get an object instead of a number.

Is there something I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks for any help in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yep! What's tripping you up is *asynchronous programming.* The problem with your test is that the second half of the test (after `Here I add an item`) is evaluated *before* `ammount = c;` is evaluated, because your first `then()` statement is still waiting for `count()` to come back. So when the `expect()` statement is hit, `ammount` still doesn't have a value and adding 1 to it won't work (because it's still null, at least for a few milliseconds). It's funny, but that's how promises work.

The following code will do the trick:

```
describe("list test", function(){
    it('Description of the test', function(){
        browser.get('app/#/list');

        var list = element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists'));

        list.count().then(function(amount) {

            // ... Here I add an item ...

            var secondAmount = element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists')).count();

            expect(secondAmount).toEqual(amount + 1);
        });
    });
});
```

It's important to wait for the `list.count()` promise to come back (asynchronously) before trying to do something with the value it returns. That's what the `then()` statement is for; it forces the rest of the test to wait for the `count()` to finish. That way everything happens in the order you expect.

This is necessary because you are using `amount + 1`. Protractor's `expect()` statements understand how to use promises, but not if you are modifying the return values. We can put the `secondAmount` promise directly inside the `expect()` statement without a `then()` function, but we cannot put `list.count() + 1` inside an `expect()` statement.

For more details, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27381352/how-to-assign-count-of-rows-or-gettext-to-a-variable-in-protractor/27949974#27949974). Try to gain a strong understanding of Node.JS asynchronous programming and Javascript promises and it will make your Protractor life so much better!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Not only does it work now but I understand what I was doing wrong! I will do a bit more research into asynchronous programming!

Comment: This is the solution, but just a suggestion on the code: the second .then() statement is not necessary.

Comment: @NemanjaMilosavljevic You're right. With the experience I've gained since writing this answer, I've realized I could clean up my code quite a bit. Thanks for drawing my attention to this.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor element functions run asynchronously and return promises.  try this...

```
describe("list test", function() {
    it('Description of the test', function () {
        browser.get('app/#/list');

        element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists')).count()
        .then(function (amount) {
            // ... Here You add an item
            element.all(by.repeater('list in listData.myLists')).count()
                .then(function (secondAmount) {
                    expect(secondAmount).toEqual(amount + 1);
                })
        })
    });
});
```